# Entity Framework strange behaviour when adding objects with multiple foreign keys in bulk

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a collection of entities that I am creating all at once. I am essentially creating a doubly linked list data structure, where each object has a Next and Previous ID. I add all of the objects to the DB Context, and then traverse through the entities, setting their Next & Previous ID's. At the end, I call SaveChangesAsync to commit the changes to the database. I have this working fine if I'm updating entities individually, but obviously this leads to performance issues and a bulk add is much more efficient. In the correct state, the first entity in the list should have a null Previous ID, and the last entity in the list should have a null Next ID.

What is strange about my bulk adding, is that the Previous ID's are coming in as null. Based on my simple (and non-refactored) code below, I am doing the exact same thing with Previous ID's that I am with Next ID's. For some reason, Entity Framework is only generating the correct ID's for Next ID. Both properties are configured the exact same way in the DB schema.

```
for(var i=0; i < added.Count; i++)
{
    if(i == 0)
    {
        added[i].Entity.Next = added[i + 1].Entity;
    }
    if(i > 0 && i < (added.Count - 1)) {
        added[i].Entity.Previous = added[i - 1].Entity;
        added[i].Entity.Next = added[i + 1].Entity;
    }
    if(i == (added.Count - 1))
    {
        added[i].Entity.Previous = added[i - 1].Entity;
    }
}
await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Results in:

[image]

Modifying the logic to specifically update the ID's like this:

```
for(var i=0; i < added.Count; i++)
{
    if(i == 0)
    {
        added[i].Entity.NextId = added[i + 1].Entity.Id;
    }
    if(i > 0 && i < (added.Count - 1)) {
        added[i].Entity.PreviousId = added[i - 1].Entity.Id;
        added[i].Entity.NextId = added[i + 1].Entity.Id;
    }
    if(i == (added.Count - 1))
    {
        added[i].Entity.PreviousId = added[i - 1].Entity.Id;
    }
}

await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Results in:

[image]

Oddly enough, in the first example (which I believe is the correct way to link entities in EF), after the SaveChanges, the debugger shows that the previous ID is null, but its navigation property contains the correct entity with the correct generated ID (not the large negative value)

[image]

[image]

Comment: how is this entity configured? especially the PK configuration and the configuration for these two columns would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is a circularity in reference and obviously not resolved automaticly.

if you have 2 items, a, b
and you link a to b, and b to a, which one you want to save first ?

The ID is generated while saving, so if you save "a" first, the id of "a" is known,
than you can save "b", with a link to "a", and you know the id of "a".
But when you have saved "a" the id of "b" was not yet known.

So this can only work in one direction.

When working with self reference tables, and you know this behavior, you always should save the items first, and set the links in a second run. This would be also not possible in a different way, when you write SQL yourself. The ID's are generated on insert and known after insert has finished.
So it's not the fault of EF when you need some update operations, after the insert.

Maybe there could be an automism for such scenarios in Entity framework, but you proofed, there isn't.

This kind of table also causes issues with navigation properties, if you don't put it to load on demand (make it virtual), or you use Include(x => x.Next) it's possible you always load the entire table, cause the entire table is a long chain of items.

For your scenario you go better with assigning a continuous number to each item. If you "orderby" this number, you have preserved your order. If you want to insert an element between to existing elements, you make this number a double (floating-point), than you can always insert an element 7.5 between the elements 7 and 8. That's much easier than updating 3 rows, just to insert one element, what you had to do with your linked-list.

To read the direct predecessor or successor is slightly slower with this method, you don't look out for a concrete ID, but for the largest ID, lower than your given idea.
But if you put an index on these reference columns, the server does it in a reasonable time. Computing the maximum of a range needs to access each element, while a search can skip a few elements, but this is not worth much thoughts unless you have gigabytes of data.